# defaultValue react hook form doesnt receive object.data

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma, react-hook-form, zustand

I'm using React Hook Form to make some Edit/Update data, getting my data from zustand, with type value any. then I save it to defaultValue from React Hook Form, I'm getting 'Undefined' when get values, but when I manually hardcode it with some strings and numbers it can be correctly getValues like I hardcode it.

[image]

What recently I update is changing type data from zustand to type data model from Prisma, where I got from table 'Report', but same nothing changed. I'm doing console log to some inputs it still get 'undefined'

Can someone help me please?

**FINAL RESULT**
it was first render, I need to add useEffect to update the value, and inside I need to call reset() API.

Answer (score 1):

`defaultValues` only apply during first render. It seems it is applying the values from report object during first render.

For subsequent render if you want to update the form values you can use [setValue](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue/)

Comment: thank you verymuch, i was not really notice and overthink.. finaly I added useEffect to call reset() api.